# Reading a stream from the right in c++

Tags: c++, stream

I'm a bit of a noob to c++. I understand that when one reads from a stream, you read from the left. e.g If you had a file with the line:

> I'm playing around with streams

When you read the file, the first string you'll retrieve from the file is `I'm`

Is it possible to make the first string you retrieve to be `streams`

Reading a stream from the right, basically.

Note: This is assuming that you don't read entire lines per time

Comment: I think you mean beginning-to-end, not left to right (and right now a whole bunch of people that read arabic and hebrew are wondering what you're talking about).

Comment: If you want to process a file line-by-line, you should read a line at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is to read the words from right to left, not the whole stream. Reading the stream from right to left would result in `smaerts` not in `streams` and I am sure you can not do that out of the box. What I suggest is that you read the words in a vector and then reverse it. Alternatively, reverse the whole string before reading from it and then reverse each word after reading it.

Answer (score 1):

Streams are not read from left to right, they're read from first to last. They are supposed to model things where this is the logical way to read them and in some cases (e.g. keyboard input) the only sensible way to read them. For a stream that is entirely known at the start (e.g. a file) you could, if you really really wanted, painstakingly seek to the last element and then read them in one-by-one seeking as you go. This would be slow and ugly.

Instead, I recommend you *read* from first to last in the usual fashion and then manipulate the data once you've got it.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no support for this in the streams library.  A file is generally arranged with the document data going from left to right, top to bottom.  Given variable length lines, you can't generally know where the line terminates unless you scan over all the data in the line.

For this requirement, you're best off reading an entire line into a string with getline, then you have many options such as:

- writing your own string scanner to find each word in turn (simple enough, fast)
- creating a istringstream from the reversed line text, then looping to stream each word in turn - reversing it back before processing (convenient for stream features - whitespace skipping, conversions, status etc.)
- tokenising the line into an array or similar, and iterating that in reverse order (simple conceptually, but memory hungry)